# Reassigning output pointer in function

Tags: c

I'm wondering why, when I run the following code, the value of `t` is the same after the call to `get` as it was before.

I have a feeling that the issue is the reassignment in line 11, at `c = tmp` - But hopefully someone can point me in the right direction?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

BOOL get(COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT f, WCHAR* c) {
    DWORD s = 0;
    WCHAR* tmp = NULL;
    GetComputerNameExW(f, tmp, &s);
    tmp = (WCHAR*)realloc(tmp, sizeof(WCHAR) * s);
    GetComputerNameExW(f, tmp, &s);
    c = tmp;
    return TRUE;
}

void _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    WCHAR* t = TEXT("thisisatest");
    BOOL res = get(ComputerNameDnsHostname, t);
    printf("%Ls\n", t);
}
```

The above code have, for the sake of brevity, been stripped of error handling code. Also, I suspect there's a race condition between the 2 calls to GetComputerNameExW().

Comment: Assigning a new value to a function's parameter has no effect outside of that function. (What do you expect to happen if you call `get(ComputerNameDnsHostname, 0)`? Would the value of `0` change?)

Comment: There can't be a race condition with synchronous calls in a single-threaded program.

Comment: Look at the signature of `realloc` closely. Note how it returns a new pointer. Have you ever wondered why it's needed?

Comment: @George "*The length of the name may be greater than `MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH` characters because DNS allows longer names. To ensure that this buffer is large enough, set this parameter to `NULL` and use the required buffer size returned in the `lpnSize` parameter.*"

Comment: is second GetComputerNameExW function and realloc For Exception Handling? example memory leak or don't believe win api.. I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply modifying the parameter copy of main's `t` pointer within the `get(COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT f, WCHAR* c)` function.

The effect is not propagated outside `get`.
You are assigning the value of tmp to a temporary pointer that is lost after `get` returns.

Pass `c` as `WCHAR** c` in `get` as follows:

```
BOOL get(COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT f, WCHAR** c){
  //stuff
  tmp = (WCHAR*)realloc(tmp, sizeof(WCHAR) * s);
  *c=tmp;
  //other stuff
}
```

Comment: So when passing in WCHAR* t as WCHAR* c in get, I'm just passing in the address of t as c and then later replacing said address with the address of WCHAR* tmp (Which, now that I think of it, I know...)

So using a pointer to a pointer would fix it, as I'd just replace the second-level pointer that the first-level pointer points to... I could live with that...

Comment: Correct, but `t` itself is never modified.